# Disabled Kendo DropDownList in Javascript

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, dropdown

Hi I'm trying to accomplished to disabled the `KendoDropDownList` via javascript.
I already did it but my problem is when I try to populate the `KendoGrid` the `KendoDropDownList` is disabled but the value is gone. Anyone know how to fix this? or Anyone know other way to do accomplished this ?

Heres my code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      var url = "@Url.Action("CheckUserStatus", "Maintenance")";
      var checkData = "CheckUser";
      $.post(url, checkData, function (d) {
          if (d != 0) {
              // alert(d);

              $("#office_id").data("kendoDropDownList").value(d);
              document.getElementById("mode-status").innerHTML = "Update Program";
              document.getElementById("button-status").innerHTML = "Update Program";
              $("#grd_ApprovedBudget").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
              $("#office_id").kendoDropDownList({
                  enable: false
              });


          }
          //alert(d);

      })
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `$("#office_id").kendoDropDownList`, it will try to create a new instance of kendoDropDownList.  If you want to disable an existing kendoDropDownList, you'll have to do it using the `enable` function of the existing instance:

```
$("#office_id").data("kendoDropDownList").enable(false);
```

Here's [kendo documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#methods-enable) about the enable function.